# SQL Group By Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct

I have a question for SQL Group By Statement

First This is my table -> temp_data

```
id    |   a_id     |      date_time         |    length  |   <br>
1074  |  3   |    2016-12-07 09:13:13.490  |  1.036013  |   <br>
1075  |  1   |    2016-12-07 09:13:13.690  |  1.699601  |   <br> 
1076  |  0   |    2016-12-07 09:13:13.867  |  2.110443  |   <br> 
1077  |  3   |    2016-12-07 09:13:14.490  |  1.027660  |   <br> 
1078  |  1   |    2016-12-07 09:13:14.690  |  1.742645  |   <br> 
1079  |  0   |    2016-12-07 09:13:14.867  |  2.121963  |   <br> 
1080  |  2   |    2016-12-07 09:13:18.390  |  4.008482  |   <br>
```

I trying select id, a_id, date_time, length for 3 different a_id order by id asc
so I use this

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a_id, 
    Min(id) id,         
    Min(Last_Data.lenght) lenght,
    (Select date_time from temp_data
     where temp_data.id = Min(Last_Data.id)) last_time
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM temp_data
    where id >= 1074 and id <= 1080
) Last_Data
GROUP BY a_id
order by id asc
```

The result is

```
id    |   a_id     |      last_time         |    length  |   <br>
1074  |  3   |    2016-12-07 09:13:13.490  |  1.013928 |   <br>
1075  |  1   |    2016-12-07 09:13:13.690  |  1.699601  |   <br>
1076  |  0   |    2016-12-07 09:13:13.867  |  2.110443  |   <br>
```

I get wrong length value for id. How can I solve this problem?

P.S. : First I get 3 different a_id in this table. Then I use select top 3* statement. Because two same a_id can come in succession. For example

```
id  |   a_id     |      date_time         |    length  |   <br>
1074  |  1   |    2016-12-07 09:13:13.490  |  1.013928 |   <br>
1075  |  1   |    2016-12-07 09:13:13.690  |  1.699601  |   <br>
```

Comment: Your query selects `last_time`, but there's no such column in the specified result... Also different column order.

Comment: @jarih I fix it

Comment: which RDMS are you using? The answer may depend on it.

Comment: How come `length` is misspelled in your query? Did you actually retype it?

Comment: @trincot Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @trincot I want to get length for specific id but this query get min length

Comment: I understand that, but I am talking about spelling. *lenght* is not *length*.

Comment: You don't need `DISTINCT` after `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `first_value` analytic function with the `over` clause:

```
select   a_id, 
         min(id) id,         
         first_value(length) over (partition by a_id order by id) length,
         first_value(date_time) over (partition by a_id order by id) last_time
where    id >= 1074 and id <= 1080
group by a_id
order by 2 asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cteData as
(    
    SELECT
        t.a_id, t.id, t.date_time, t.lenght,
        row_number() over(partition by t.a_id order by t.date_time desc) rn
    FROM temp_data t
    where id >= 1074 and id <= 1080
)
select
   d.a_id, d.id, d.date_time as last_date_time, t.length
from cteData d
where d.rn = 1
```